# QuickBooks Web Connector Select a QBPOS server popup

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

Everytime my application runs in Quickbooks Web Connector, its asks me to Select a QBPOS Server

So every time my application runs in Quickbooks Web Connector (currently set at every 2 minutes), its runs the application and than when "Connecting to QB Point-of-Sale..." is displayed a pop up comes up saying "Select a QBPOS Server". Than it shows a list of the available server. I click "OK" and the application runs. Unfortunately every time it runs I have to select the server and click "OK". Any way that it can select it automatically every time?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVepH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved this.
First, found here http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_web_connector this note:

"For QuickBooks Point-of-Sale: You must specify the connection string (e.g.: Computer Name=qbposserver;Company Data=My Company;Version=9) in the response from the authenticate() web service method. If you don't know this, the “POS SDK Test” utility included with the QuickBooks POS SDK can generate this for you."

Then searched in Keith Plamer's SDK, I ve found that its possible to override the default authenticate function. Example is here: docs/example_web_connector_auth.php

In my case it needed the qb_company_file param to be set like this:

function _quickbooks_custom_auth($username, $password, &$qb_company_file) {

```
    if ($username == 'quickbooks' and
            $password == 'password')
    {
            // Use this company file and auth successfully
            $qb_company_file = 'Computer Name=desktop-o05dkv4;Company Data=swe12new;Version=12';

            return true;
    }

    // Login failure
    return false;
```

}

And after that, it stopped to ask for server path.